# Minecraft 1.10: How to make an item in the off-hand give buff

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering how to make an item give a potion buff or generic boost when held ONLY in the off-hand.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Showing effort to solve your own problems means you get a better reception

Comment: This site is much more friendly than other sites.  Plus, some articles aren't that explicit, such as Minecraft Wiki.  Also, people that have a question like this can look here for information.  Not only am I helping myself out, but others, too.

Comment: Yes. And for things like Minecraft, you get a much better reception when there's research behind your question. We want *interesting* questions, which require effort.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish a "generic boost" is through attributes, which can be set to only apply on a specific slot. [This is a generator that allows adding attributes to items for specific slots.](http://server.cloudcraft.fr/give/) Here's an example command that gives you 10 extra health (5 hearts) when held only in the offhand:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Slot:"offhand",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:91328,UUIDLeast:135212}]}
```

[There's this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute) if you want to learn more about all the things attributes can do, and what do different operations are for.

Though there's a few things attributes do better than potions effects, they're a bit limited and may not be able to do what you want.

---

Alternatively, you could do this by detecting when the player is holding the item in their offhand slot (-106)

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=OffhandHoldingItem] remove OffhandHoldingItem
/scoreboard players tag @a add OffhandHoldingItem {Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Example Sword"}}}]}
```

You can then do anything you want to the player, such as:

```
/effect @a[tag=OffhandHoldingItem] jump_boost 1
```